# pinia composition api 'this' type problem

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, pinia

I am using Nuxt 2 with Pinia Composition API. Through a plugin, I have added axios instances, etc., into PiniaCustomProperties.

```
const piniaPlugin = ({ $pinia, app }: { $pinia: any; app: any }): void => {
  $pinia.use(({ store }: { store: any }) => {
    store.$axios = app.$axios;
  });
};
```

But when I try to access them using 'this'.

```
export const useOnboardingStore = defineStore('onboarding', () => {
  async function getNotifications (): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.$axios.get<Array<NotificationRaw>>(BASE_URL);
```

I get an error: TS2683:  this  implicitly has type  any  because it does not have a type annotation.

At the same time, the code works. The error is only in TS. Moreover, if I use the same thing in Options API (width object state, actions etc.), there is no error and 'this' is properly typed.

So far, I have no ideas on how to fix the problem.